# How to get a randomn row from Parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have such problem:
In me Parse server I've created several objects in class name "Job"
My goal is after clickig on button send object's fields to special LabelName.text field. So by clicking I change objects randomnly.

Here is my code for static retriving objects

```
 func retriveJobData() {
    var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Jobs")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("AUeuvj0zk2") {
        (newJobObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil && newJobObject != nil {
            println(newJobObject)

            if let newJobObject = newJobObject {

            self.PrcieTextField.text = newJobObject["jobPrice"] as? String

            self.DateTextField.text = newJobObject["jobDate"] as? String

            self.DescriptionTextField.text = newJobObject["jobDescription"] as? String

            }
        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my implementation my random choice.
I couldn't find any info whether Parse automatically gives number to their rows.

```
func retriveaDataRandomn() {
    var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Jobs")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            var count  = query.countObjects()
            var randomnNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
            var randomnNumberCast = Int(randomnNumber)
            query.whereKey("WhatShouldIwriteHere", equalTo: randomnNumberCast)

            query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if error == nil && newJobObject != nil {
                    //the same code as above in static retriving
                }

            })

        }

    }
}
```

Thanks for help, anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to pick a random element by querying? You could just pick a random element of the objects-array the first query gives you:

```
let randomIndex = Int(arc4random()) % query.countObjects
let randomObject = objects![randomIndex]
```

Notice that you should make sure objects is not nil.